# Mongoid query by referenced collection

Tags: mongoid3

An example will be the best to describe my question

got this 2 documents

{ a : [] }
{ a  [{x:1,y:2},{x:3,y:4}]

so both docs have this a attr
one empty one not

how can i select only a's that their array is not empty?

lets say model name is Model

I tried 
Model.not.with_size(a:0)

without success

any direction?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Model.where(:a.not => {'$size' => 0})
```